# Creating a header for better conversions

Tags: user-behavior, conversion, conversion-rate

My current header is showing site navigation at the very top. The links don't have any call of action, and they are duplication in the footer. I am sure this part of the site is some valuable real estate, shouldn't I have something more compelling to get orders there?

[image: header]

Some ideas I had to replace it are, add some USPs there (free shipping, guarantee, etc). Add a search bar there. Add the contact phone there, and a search bar where the existing phone is. Any suggestions or ideas from experience or education?

Answer (score 2):

That real estate on the website is not as valuable as you think it is.  Users expect navigation at the top so they can explore the site.  Users eyes tend to go down the left side and across the middle, which is why most sites use a promo image slider just below the top navigation.  This is an interesting article about the f-layout and zigzag ( http://www.trewmarketing.com/smartmarketingblog/marketing-trends/using-science-to-guide-web-design-3-key-takeaways-from-eyetracking-research/).  Stick to traditional web design, it works for a reason.

Comment: Not to mention, space is your friend.  Clean and simple FTW.